# Getting illegal argument exception when turning subsection of list into array

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, illegalargumentexception

I have a list `linePoints` which is a list of `Point`s.

```
private List<Point> linePoints = new ArrayList<>();
```

I also have a list of Point[]s called polygons.

```
private List<Point[]> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have a method that is supposed to do a few things and then convert part of `linePoints` into a `Point[]` which is supposed to be added to polygons.

This is the relevant code:

```
   //"p" is a point and "i" is a integer
   //The code is supposed to take part of linePoints and turn it into a Point[] in polygons.
   List tempList;
   tempList = linePoints.subList(linePoints.indexOf(p),i); //The problem is on this line
                                                          // I get a "IllegalArgumentException"
    polygons.add((Point[]) tempList.toArray());
```

Why am I getting an illegal argument exception?

EDIT 1: I did some testing and found if I replaced

```
            tempList = linePoints.subList(linePoints.indexOf(p),i);
```

with

```
tempList = linePoints.subList(0,1);
```

It would work.

EDIT 2: I found the solution. Turns out the first parameter of the line was larger then the second.

Now I have another problem though, in the line:

```
polygons.add((Point[]) tempList.toArray());
```

I get the exception that I cannot cast the Object[] array returned by

```
tempList.toArray()
```

into a Point[].

Comment: Are you sure that `linePoints.indexOf(p)` doesn't return -1?

Comment: Before the problematic line add `System.out.println(p instanceof Point);System.out.println(i); System.out.println(linePoints.indexOf(p);` and add the output of these lines to your post.

Comment: @engineer I solved the problem, turned out I just had to switch the arguments (the 1st one was larger then the second) now I have a new problem though that I put in my post.

Comment: Change `(Point[]) tempList.toArray()` to `Arrays.copyOf(tempList.toArray(), tempList.toArray().length, Point[].class);` ...

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
private List<Point> linePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
private List<Point[]> polygons = new ArrayList<Point[]>();
```

Comment: Yes, because this is the old style. Now he can use the diamond operator.

Comment: How about this: List<Point[]> tempList;